# Accepted answer + upvote were shown as +17 achievement

Tags: support, reputation, achievements-dialog

Not tagging as "bug" since I am not sure I can reproduce it again.

Recently, [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34281139/select-method-in-beautifulsoup-not-able-to-select-attribute-value-with-white-spa/34281169#34281169) was accepted and upvoted (while I was editing it). And I remember having no new achievement notifications. But, instead of expected +25, +17 showed up:

[image]

Apologies if I'm misunderstanding something and there is a simple explanation to that.

Comment: Probably some questions you downvoted got deleted at the same time... Reversal of negative votes don't show up in the list...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov in that case the indicator should be higher than the list.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

tl;DR: the post from which you got those 8 points was deleted.

Maybe, and I say *maybe*, 4 posts in which you suggested edits were deleted, in which case you lost 8 reputation (which would make sense considering that you reported this just an hour and 45 minutes after roomba ran), or an answer that got an upvote and one downvote (net +8) was deleted.

Both can be verified if you go to the reputation tab in your user activity page and select "show removed posts".

Comment: Or 4 mystery downvotes?

Comment: @ryanyuyu AFAIK downvotes to your posts are shown on the achievements breakdown always.

Comment: Yeah that's right.  They just don't cause the red notification box to appear on their own.

Comment: Suggested edits? From how long ago? He's a little ways past 2k...

Comment: @CaptJak yeah, I still get random -2 from stuff I edited in '13.

Answer (score 4):

The rep notification sometimes does numbers in aggregate because it doesn't always notify you of negative reputation (especially if you were the source of the negative rep). Let's say you answer a question and downvote another (`-1` rep). Then you get an upvote on your answer (`+10`). The system will notify you of a `+9`, even if the `-1` was yesterday. You will never get a `-1` notice because it's assumed you know you made a downvote.

If you go into your profile and click the **Reputation** tab it will show you the entire chain of reputation

[image]

Comment: Reputation changes of non-delete post always appear on the achievements breakdown, independently of what causes the changes.

Comment: @Braiam You're right but the **aggregate credit** sometimes lags behind

Comment: I'm fairly certain this has happened to me. If I received an upvote and also downvoted something around the same time, I see aggregate +9 for the achievement notification, and when I click it, the dropdown only shows the +10 for the upvote, not the -1 for the downvote.